# The NVIDIA X driver is not new enough to support the nvidia-settings Display Configuration page

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors

I've been trying without success to configure dual monitors on 12.04, I've installed the nvidia drivers but the gui tool doesn't seem to support my graphics card.

[image: nvidia settings]

Any Idea on how to resolve this?

Oh, and the output from

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
$ 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G86 [Quadro NVS 290] (rev a1)
```

Comment: The problem seem to be the graphics card, it only had one DVI port and I was using a splitter to connect an additional monitor. Which worked great in windows. Ubuntu doesn't seem to detect the second monitor though.

Comment: I have this issue with a graphics card with two VGA ports, the card worked fine with two (non-mirrored) monitors on a different machine (with 9.04).

Comment: For me i solved it too switching from "(version current) [Recommended]" to "(post-release updates) (version current-updates)" in Additional Drivers aplication.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved for me by switching from "(version current) [Recommended]" to "(post-release updates) (version current-updates)"
.

Comment: Can I ask where you made this switch? Thanks.

Comment: Switch is made in "Additional Drivers". You can find this in "System Settings" or do a search in the dash.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this worked for me:

1. Open "System Settings" -> "Additional drivers"
2. Select "NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (version current)" and click "Activate"
3. Reboot

Comment: I've done that several times with different versions of the drivers. I've even recompiled the kernel with the new drivers, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 10.04.

I had to install "*`nvidia-settings` - Tool of configuring the NVDIA graphics driver*" via Software Center. That solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and solved it by removing the (too new) nvidia-settings. After that I had to reinstall the nvidia-settings belonging to the installed nvidia-kernel (in my case 295.40).